# Call a separate Python script in Django Views present at same location

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django project name 'myproject' & app name 'dbapp' like this -

```
myproject
|
|----dbapp
       |
       |----model.py
       |      :
       |----views.py
       |
       |----start.py
```

I want to run a Python script name 'start.py' through Django Views.

I am using this syntax -

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def page(request, uuid):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        call(["python3", "start.py"])
        return Response('dbname')
```

Python Script - 'start.py' call 2 other python scripts like this -

```
call(["python3", "create_host.py"])

call(["python3", "create_main.py"])
```

If I run start.py, it works as expected running both the called python files.

But Django Views is giving error when it call start.py script using given syntax. Error -

```
python3: can't open file 'start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I call a separate python file through Django views.

I even tried this syntax -
call(["python3", "urldbapp/start.py"])

This gives error like this -
python3: can't open file 'start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What syntax should I use?

P.S. - 'start.py' is a small Python script but it further calls 2 Python scripts.

Comment: you can just import methods from that file and call them.

Comment: I dont have a function/class in start.py. @ruddra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default the directory of execution is the location of your manage.py file

To fix this, replace the path to your file with absolute paths: `call(["python3", "/home/gaurav/folder1/folder2/start.py"])`

Do the same for other files being imported through start.py